# Publish in Visual Studio 2019 Not working

Tags: visual-studio-2019

When I try to publish my application to a local folder in Visual Studio 2019, it builds successfully then nothing happens. There's no mention of whether the publish succeeded or failed. No files are published. When I look at the Web Publish Activity tab, I see the Overall status progress bar keeps going and going and the View Details shows nothing. Has anyone seen this issue or have any idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my configuration in the Configuration Manager is called Dev and in the .csproj file this existed:

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'DEV|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

Changing DEV to Dev made it work.